# How did software copyright work in the US before 1978?

Tags: copyright, software

Prior to the Copyright Act of 1976 (which, confusingly, only went into effect in 1978) the copyright rules were different. One of the things that was introduced was that after the beginning of 1978, software could be explicitly copyrighted.

So, what about software which was published *before* 1978? I've seen a variety of opinions.

- that it can't be copyrighted at all.
- that the representation of the software can be copyrighted. For example, a magnetic tape containing the program, or a journal article with a listing in it. But the program itself can't be.
- that the source code, being a literary work, can be copyrighted, but the object code which can't be read by humans can't be.
- that it works the same way as it does today (although with an expiry date of publish + 28 + 28 years).

The reason why this is interesting is that it may or may not make pre-1978 software public domain in certain circumstances, even if it was published with a copyright notice.

Does anyone actually know about any of this? Finding information on pre-1978 copyright is like pulling hen's teeth. The closest I can find here is this answer: [US Copyright Status of Software Source Code Created Prior to 1980?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77988/us-copyright-status-of-software-source-code-created-prior-to-1980/77989#77989) ...except it doesn't really answer my question and also has a score of -1, which makes me very suspicious of it.

Comment: FWIW, software was in its infancy prior to 1978 and mostly involved one off custom products in that time period.

Comment: Its a little extreme to say that object-code can't be read by humans.  We cannot read it as smoothly as we read our native language, but a skilled programmer can sit down and start translating hex-encoded bytes to machine op-codes.  Its more akin to painstakingly translating ancient hieroglyphics, but it is possible.

Comment: @abelenky That's a different kind of reading --- humans can _understand_ it, but they can't _read_ it once it's encoded into, e.g., a ROM. It requires transcription into a different form first.

Comment: @DavidGiven so does “War and Peace” encoded in ASCII. Or French. Doesn’t mean that, with enough time and effort, a human couldn’t learn to read binary natively.

Comment: @DaleM But I doubt any court would find that you had produced a new, separately copyrightable work by encoding War and Peace in ASCII.